# How to access form data from ejs template and update it in sqlite3

Tags: html, node.js, express, ejs

I have created a form inside of an ejs templating file and I want to update the data inside of my sqlite3 database when I click the button, here's my ejs file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Add User Record</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>create a user record here</h1>
    <form action="create-user-record" method="post">
        <input id = "record" type = "text" name = "test_record_value" value = "" required/>
        <br>
        <button type="submit" >Create a new user record</button>
    </form>
    <br>
    <a style = "color:black; font-size: 30px;" href = "\user\get-user-records"> View available records</a>
</body>
</html>
```

and here's the code in my middleware:

```
router.post("/create-user-record", (req, res, next) => {
  let record_value = req.body.test_record_value;
  global.db.run(
    "INSERT INTO testUserRecords ('test_record_value', 'test_user_id') VALUES( ?, ? );",
    [record_value, 1],
    function (err) {
      if (err) {
        next(err);
      } else {
        res.send(`New data inserted @ id ${this.lastID}!`);
        next();
      }
    }
  );
});
```

the error I get when I try to do it this way is 'cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'test_record_value'), I know I am probably not accessing it incorrectly

how can I achieve this ?

EDIT: I needed to include this `app.use(express.json({ extended: true }));` and `app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));` I am not sure which one of these worked with my issue, but I included both just in case :)